# How to pass the useState setter as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a code which flips between a dark theme and light theme on button click as follows:

App.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import { ChangeTheme } from "./functions/ChangeTheme";

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark-theme");

  const changeTheme = (theme) => {
    return theme === "dark-theme" ? setTheme("") : setTheme("dark-theme");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card theme={theme} changeTheme={() => ChangeTheme(theme)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Card.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./Card.scss";

const Card = ({ theme, changeTheme }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={theme}>Card title</div>
      <button onClick={changeTheme}>Click me</button>
    </>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Card.scss:

```
.dark-theme {
  color: green;
}
```

Code above working well. Working example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-water-y1j0o

Now I'd like to extract the `changeTheme` to a separate function. I tried to pass both `theme` and `setTheme` as parameters to `ChangeTheme`:

ChangeTheme.js

```
export const ChangeTheme = ({ theme, setTheme }) => {
  return theme === "dark-theme" ? setTheme("") : setTheme("dark-theme");
};
```

And used it in `App.js` like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import { ChangeTheme } from "./functions/ChangeTheme";

export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark-theme");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card theme={theme} changeTheme={() => ChangeTheme(theme, setTheme)} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I got the error: `setTheme is not a function`, any idea why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Two parameters to the function and not one

update with codesandbox :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/holy-thunder-tbgd6

and improve the conditional (ternary) operator

```
export const changeTheme = (theme, setTheme) => {
  setTheme(theme === "dark-theme" ? "" : "dark-theme");
};
```

Comment: The `Card` component uses the object destructuring in arguments. Maybe its better to maintain the same signature. Agree about conditional ternary operator.

Comment: Also agree about using `changeTheme` (`camelCase`) for a non-component function.

Comment: the Card is a component, the changeTheme is function, it's can be with one parameter but with two it's more clear for me, value and setter.
BTW I would use useToggle of react-use library :)

Comment: `useToggle of react-use library` me too ;P

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the arguments as object keys in `App.js`:

```js
// Lacks {}
ChangeTheme(theme, setTheme)

// Change to:
ChangeTheme({theme, setTheme})
```

So, `App` component becomes:

```js
export default function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("dark-theme");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Card theme={theme} changeTheme={() => ChangeTheme({theme, setTheme})} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I tried `<Card theme={theme} changeTheme={() => ChangeTheme({theme, setTheme})} />` and got error: `(0 , _ChangeTheme.ChangeTheme) is not a function`

Comment: Can you post full `functions/ChangeTheme.js` contents? Maybe its better to export it as default (and import it as such).